# AS3 Append data to local file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an AS3 game that will be played on local desktops (not on network) and I need to save the players details after every game.
I have tried a few methods (filestream, sharedObject, XML) but so far none have worked.
The details to be saved are variables player_name and player_score.  I just need these added to an existing file, they don't have to be sorted or filtered.

Comment: filestream or at the very least sharedobject should have worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case I would use a simple LocalShardObject. I hope, you'll understand this code. Otherways, please ask. Greetings André

```
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.net.SharedObject;    

var soName:String="yourSO"

function writeScore(playerName:String, playerScore:Number):void
{
    var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(soName);    
    // Write a new Object nemed by the playername in the so 
    so.data[playerName]= {name:PlayerName, playerScore:playerScore};    
    // add a successListener
    so.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onFlushStatus);
    // and flush it
    so.flush(); 
}

function readSO():Object
{
    var so:SharedObject; = SharedObject.getLocal(soName);

    //If no lso was found
    if (so.size === 0 || so.data.results === null)  {               
         _results = [];
        trace("lso not found"); 
        return;             
    }
    //For 'playerName' you can choose a name you want and add all your stuff to  this object // it is basically an object
    var playerName:String = so.data[playerName]name;
    var playerScore:Number = so.data[playerName]playerScore;
    trace(playerName, playerScore); 
}

function onFlushStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void
{           
    var so:SharedObject = event.target as SharedObject; 
    switch (event.info.code)
    {
        case "SharedObject.Flush.Success":
            trace("value saved in the lso"); 
        break;
        case "SharedObject.Flush.Failed":
            trace( "value not saved in the lso"); 
        break;
    }

    so.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onFlushStatus);
}

//Let' try
writeScore("Andre", 10);
readSO("Andre");
writeScore("JayTray", 11);
readSO("JayTray");
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, How reliable and stable are these sharedobject files?  I have been testing them this week and they are holding all data, I'm just afraid that they expire and lose all saved information after X days - is this the case, do you know?  Thanks again

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d80.html#WSc3ff6d0ea7785946-5718d4e1205d835fd0-7fff 
says:
shared objects have the following properties:

They do not expire by default.
By default, they are limited to a size of 100 KB each.
They can store simple data types (such as String, Array, and Date).
They are stored in a location specified by the application (within the user’s home directory).
They are never transmitted between the client and server.

They are as stable and reliable as the user doesn't delete them ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write on the file system, you must use AIR. It's a wrapper of Flash Player + tons of features that work with the specific file system. It can run on different ones, including mobile, and it will provide you with the needed functionality.

Flash Player alone won't be able to use the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileStream` with [`FileMode.APPEND`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileMode.html).

```
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(myFile, FileMode.APPEND);
fileStream.writeUTFBytes("\n" + myData);
fileStream.close();
```